# Google Apps Script Cannot Find Browser Class

Tags: google-apps-script

So I began experimenting with Google Apps script (to automate a google slide maker), so I created a test function. This is all the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  Browser.msgBox("Hello World");
}
```

This gives me an error: Exception: Cannot call Browser.msgBox() from this context; have you tried Logger.log() instead? (line 2, file "Code"). Before I verified and allowed authorization, when I typed Browser. it would give me options. After I authorized, nothing popped up. This means that the authorization is the problem. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Also, google never made me type "continue" during the authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Browser class is only available for Google Sheets, not Google Slides. See its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser):

> This class provides access to dialog boxes specific to Google Sheets.
>
> The methods in this class are only available for use in the context of a Google Spreadsheet. Please use [Google Workspace dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) instead.